Regex to get desired output having parenthesis
"So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30, 2, 1)"

Desired Output: ['(Review 30, 2, 1)', 30, 2, 1]

"So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30)"

Desired Output: ['(Review 30)', 30]

I am trying to get above desired output using regex but I am unable to get desired result.

I want to get string inside parenthesis as well as all numbers inside parenthesis.

I want to get parenthesis removed from string and get remaining string.



Desired output: "So happy with the performance of this object"



console.log("So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30, 2, 1)".match(/\((.*?)\)/)[0].match(/([([0-9]+)\)/));




Once you get your match with .match(/\((.*?)\)/), simply run .match(/\d+/g) on it.

If you want to get your output in a single match operation then use:


const arr = ['So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30, 2, 1)',
           'So happy with the performance of this object (Review 50)'];
const re= /(?<=\(Review\s+(?:\d+,\s*)*)\d+(?=(?:,\s*\d+)*\))/g;

arr.forEach( el => {
  var res = [el];
  [...el.matchAll(re)].forEach(m => res.push(m[0]))
  console.log(res);
});



Output:
["So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30, 2, 1)", "30", "2", "1"]
["So happy with the performance of this object (Review 50)", "50"]

RegEx Demo
RegEx Demo:

(?<=\(Review\s+(?:\d+,\s*)*): Lookbehind to assert that we have Review then 1+ whitespace then 0 or more digits separated by comma before current position
\d+: Match 1+ digits
(?=(?:,\s*\d+)*\)): Lookahead to assert that we have 0 or more digits separated by comma and ending with a ) after the current position


You have a closing parenthesis in your second regex ([([0-9]+)\) You can see what it matches here https://regex101.com/r/NoWt7G/1
Apart from that, you can remove the opening parenthesis from the character class as well as the surrounding capture group. Also you have to use the /g flag to get all matches.
What you might do it make use of a callback to match all numbers in the match for the parenthesis with \d+ or with word boundaries to prevent partial word matches \b\d+\b


[
  "So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30, 2, 1)",
  "So happy with the performance of this object (Review 30)"
].forEach(s => {
  const parts = [];
  const replaced = s.replace(/\([^()]*\)/g, m => {
    parts.push(m);
    parts.push(...m.match(/\b\d+\b/g));
    return "";
  });
  console.log(replaced);
  console.log(parts);
})



Note if there has to be at least a single digit present in the match, you can change the regex to
\([^()\d]*\d[^()]*\)

See a regex demo.
